# How to set image to a scene background in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

The title says it all, I guess.

How to set a `.jpg` (or any other supported image format) image to a Scene background?

I *somewhat* achieved this by using a `HBox`, an `Image` and an `ImageView`, like this:

```
String url = ...
HBox box= new HBox();
Image x = new Image(url);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(x);
box.getChildren().add(iv);
box.setVisible(true);
```

Then I add that box to the Scene first, and everything else afterwards.

I'm not complaining about that piece of code - it works for my purposes - but is there a proper way to set a background?

Answer (score 5):

An [`ImagePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html) can be used as [`fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#fillProperty) of the `Scene`:

```
ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(myImage);
scene.setFill(pattern);
```

Comment: I'm using this approach but nothing is happening ?

Answer (score 4):

Just call [`setBackground`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) on the root node of the scene. For example:

```
Pane root = ... ; // probably some pane subclass...
String url = ... ;
Image img = new Image(url);
BackgroundImage bgImg = new BackgroundImage(img, 
    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
    BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, 
    new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, false, false, true, false));

// put stuff in root as normal....

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) for the parameters for the `BackgroundImage` constructor, etc.

Comment: The thing is, my root was a `Group`, not a pane subclass. It's parent class is not `Region` (funny enough, it is `Parent`). Therefore it does not have `setBackground` method. No way around this, then? root node must be subclass of `Region`?

Comment: Can't you just change it to be a `Pane`? Wouldn't a `Group` and a `Pane` behave identically if they are the root of the scene...?

Comment: Also note, that, if you do choose to use a Pane rather than a Group for your scene root, then the [styling of the background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) for that pane can be externalized from your code into a CSS stylesheet (if you wish).